# Getting 404 errors when trying to install clang and libclang-dev packages using ‘apt install’

Tags: apt, pureos

I am running into 404 errors when trying to install clang and libclang-dev packages using ‘apt install’ on **PureOS**.

I am seeing the following error messages when running the command `sudo apt install clang`

```
Err:1 https://repo.pureos.net/pureos amber/main amd64 libclang-common-7-dev amd64 1:7.0.1-8
404 Not Found [IP: 138.201.228.45 443]
Err:2 https://repo.pureos.net/pureos amber/main amd64 libclang1-7 amd64 1:7.0.1-8
404 Not Found [IP: 138.201.228.45 443]
Err:3 https://repo.pureos.net/pureos amber/main amd64 clang-7 amd64 1:7.0.1-8
404 Not Found [IP: 138.201.228.45 443]
Err:4 https://repo.pureos.net/pureos amber/main amd64 libomp5-7 amd64 1:7.0.1-8
404 Not Found [IP: 138.201.228.45 443]
Err:5 https://repo.pureos.net/pureos amber/main amd64 libomp-7-dev amd64 1:7.0.1-8
404 Not Found [IP: 138.201.228.45 443]
Err:6 https://repo.pureos.net/pureos amber/main amd64 llvm-7-runtime amd64 1:7.0.1-8
404 Not Found [IP: 138.201.228.45 443]
Err:7 https://repo.pureos.net/pureos amber/main amd64 llvm-7 amd64 1:7.0.1-8
404 Not Found [IP: 138.201.228.45 443]
Err:8 https://repo.pureos.net/pureos amber/main amd64 llvm-7-dev amd64 1:7.0.1-8
404 Not Found [IP: 138.201.228.45 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://repo.pureos.net/pureos/pool/main/l/llvm-toolchain-7/libclang-common-7-dev_7.0.1-8_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 138.201.228.45 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://repo.pureos.net/pureos/pool/main/l/llvm-toolchain-7/libclang1-7_7.0.1-8_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 138.201.228.45 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://repo.pureos.net/pureos/pool/main/l/llvm-toolchain-7/clang-7_7.0.1-8_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 138.201.228.45 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://repo.pureos.net/pureos/pool/main/l/llvm-toolchain-7/libomp5-7_7.0.1-8_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 138.201.228.45 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://repo.pureos.net/pureos/pool/main/l/llvm-toolchain-7/libomp-7-dev_7.0.1-8_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 138.201.228.45 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://repo.pureos.net/pureos/pool/main/l/llvm-toolchain-7/llvm-7-runtime_7.0.1-8_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 138.201.228.45 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://repo.pureos.net/pureos/pool/main/l/llvm-toolchain-7/llvm-7_7.0.1-8_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 138.201.228.45 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://repo.pureos.net/pureos/pool/main/l/llvm-toolchain-7/llvm-7-dev_7.0.1-8_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 138.201.228.45 443]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

similar happens with libclang-dev:

```
Err:1 https://repo.pureos.net/pureos amber/main amd64 libclang1-7 amd64 1:7.0.1-8
404 Not Found [IP: 138.201.228.45 443]
Err:2 https://repo.pureos.net/pureos amber/main amd64 libclang-common-7-dev amd64 1:7.0.1-8
404 Not Found [IP: 138.201.228.45 443]
Err:3 https://repo.pureos.net/pureos amber/main amd64 libclang-7-dev amd64 1:7.0.1-8
404 Not Found [IP: 138.201.228.45 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://repo.pureos.net/pureos/pool/main/l/llvm-toolchain-7/libclang1-7_7.0.1-8_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 138.201.228.45 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://repo.pureos.net/pureos/pool/main/l/llvm-toolchain-7/libclang-common-7-dev_7.0.1-8_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 138.201.228.45 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://repo.pureos.net/pureos/pool/main/l/llvm-toolchain-7/libclang-7-dev_7.0.1-8_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 138.201.228.45 443]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Browsing the https://repo.pureos.net/pureos/pool/main/l/llvm-toolchain-7, I can see the packages are there, but all of them have a “+deb10u2” included in the name. For example, if you look at the first 404 you'll see apt is trying to find a package with the name **libclang-common-7-dev_7.0.1-8_amd64.deb**, but the package on the repository is named **libclang-common-7-dev_7.0.1-8+deb10u2_amd64.deb**.

I only face this problem with these two specific packages, I've used apt to install several other packages and everything worked fine.

I already tried the solutions suggested by apt (“maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?”). In fact, when I try running `apt install` with `--fix-missing`, I get an additional error line which says: “Unable to correct missing packages.”

I also tried using apt-get instead, and I also tried running a clean, update and upgrade before installing the package with both apt and apt-get, but also without success.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is temporarily move the `sources.list` file out of APT's directory, run `apt update` (this, I guess, will refresh the cached data), move the file back and run `apt update` again. Essentially:

```
$ sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list /tmp/
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo mv /tmp/sources.list /etc/apt/
$ sudo apt update
```

Now you should be able to fetch packages normally.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks !

Comment: @OlivierGiniaux Glad to hear that!